# Shapefiles won't load or load as blank

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I'm brand new to QGIS and the world of geo mapping tools.

I try to load a .shp file but the nothing seems to happen. The shapefile is good as it can be opened by two other users. I have tried dragging it onto a new project and adding it as a Vector layer, but nothing seems to happen.  It looks like it has loaded when I look at the layers section of the screen - though it has a green dot next to it.

I have seen a thread with someone with a similar problem in 2020 but the thread is very hard to follow if you are a newcomer to mapping tools and I don't think it was concluded.

Any ideas anyone?

[image]

---

Key to solution was looking at the layer feature count. Turns out that when I saved the files from outlook to my hard drive, somehow they got corrupted. I deleted and saved them again. Dragged them onto QGIS and all is well.

Comment: I suggest you move your shape layer above the base map layer in the layer window.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I've changed the order but still nothing happening. Is the green dot by the side of the layer - which is a shp file, have any relevance? Should a shp file have a different symbol?

Comment: Please include a link to the 2020 “thread” you saw.

Comment: Do you only have the .shp file, or do you have all the files required by the shapefile format ~ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile

Comment: could you right-click the uk urban areas layer and check "show feature count"? and provided this shows something >0, right-click and select "zoom to layer"?

Comment: The green dot indicates the symbology of your layer. Your data should appear as one or more green dots on the map (depending on how many urban areas you have in your dataset).

Comment: Maybe your data is not projected at the right location. This is what you can try: right-click on your layer in the Layers panel and choose "Zoom to layer". It will take you to where your data is in the world.

Comment: Feature count shows 0. What does this tell me?

Comment: that this shapefile contains no data.

Comment: Here is the 2020 link that looks similar to my issue. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/37527

Comment: So if feature count is 0 but the same shp file is OK on friends installation, How do I resolve the issue? It's a new laptop and installed QGIS yesterday and have not changed any settings.

Comment: Please cut/paste your solution from the area reserved for questions to the area reserved for answers.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by Erik in the comments, the order of the layers in your "Layers" pannel matters. The layers at the top of the list are also "on top" on the map. Currently, your OpenStreetMap basemap is showing on top. As it is opaque, you cannot see the shapefile underneath.
To change the order of the layers, you can simply click and drag them.

Answer (score 2):

In this context I would like to point out the "layer order panel". In some cases It might make sense to have some sort of thematically order in the "layer panel", like some sort of legend, which might lead to an unwanted rendering order in the map canvas.

[image]

In such cases you can override the display order defined in the layer tree.

[image]

Check "control rendering order" and see what happens in your example!

Comment: Ive changed the order but still nothing. Its a new installation so I have not changed any settings but frustrating that others just drag and drop the shp file onto a project and all is well.

Comment: Checking the Control rendering order box did nothing.

Comment: I recommend to check it out with your repaired data, its quit a helpful tool to keep track in large projects!